# How to import data from MySql into Hive using Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to import data from MySql to Hive using `QueryDatabaseTable` and `PutHiveQl` processors, but an error occurs.

I have some questions:

1. What is the output format of `puthiveql`?
2. Should the output table be created beforehand or will the processor do that?
3. Where can I find a template for the MySql to Hive process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some information about your questions:

1. The flow files input to PutHiveQL are output after they have been sent to Hive (or if the send fails), so the output format (and contents) are identical to the input format/contents.
2. The output table should be created beforehand, but you could send PutHiveQL a "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" statement first and it will create the table for you.
3. I'm not aware of an existing template, but a basic approach could be the following:

QueryDatabaseTable -> ConvertAvroToJSON -> SplitJson -> EvaluateJsonPath -> UpdateAttribute (optional) -> ReplaceText -> PutHiveQL

- QueryDatabaseTable will do incremental fetches of your MySQL table.
- ConvertAvroToJSON will get the records into a format you can
  manipulate (there currently aren't many processors that handle Avro)
- SplitJson will create a flow file for each of the records/rows
- EvaluateJsonPath can extract values from the records and put them in
  flow file attributes
- UpdateAttribute could add attributes containing type information.
  This is optional, used if you are using prepared statements for
  PutHiveQL
- ReplaceText builds a HiveQL statement (INSERT, e.g.) either with
  parameters (if you want prepared statements) or hard-coded values
  from the attributes
- PutHiveQL executes the statement(s) to get the records into Hive

In NiFi 1.0, there will be a [ConvertAvroToORC](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1663) processor, this is a more efficient way to get data into Hive (as well as to query it from Hive). That approach is to convert the results of QueryDatabaseTable to ORC files, which are then placed in HDFS (using PutHDFS), and it generates a partial Hive DDL statement to create the table for you (using the type information from the Avro records). You pass that statement (after filling in the target location) to PutHiveQL, and you can immediately start querying your table.

There are also plans for a [PutHiveStreaming](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1868) processor which takes Avro records as input, so that flow would just be QueryDatabaseTable -> PutHiveStreaming, which would insert the records directly into Hive (and is much more efficient than multiple INSERT statements).

Comment: HI, in which processor should i mention create statement. thanks in advance

Comment: PutHiveQL is the one that takes DDL statements like CREATE TABLE, the statement needs to be the contents of the flow file, you may find ReplaceText a good way to put your DDL in the body.

Comment: Can we supply multiple INSERT statements to PutHiveQL inside one flowfile?  For example the result of ReplaceText is a string of 20 insert statements.  If this is possible, how to construct 20 insert statements on each flowfile?
For the PutHiveStreaming, it can put data directly from database to Hive but you cannot do any manipulation of data along the way right?  You still need to go through the approach you mentioned on #3 above.

Comment: At present (NiFi 1.1.0 and below), you cannot put multiple INSERT statements to PutHiveQL, there is an improvement case (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3031) to add this capability

Comment: As of NiFi 1.2.0, you can send multiple statements in a flow file to PutHiveQL